# Meaning of ' I am so digging into it'

Tags: idioms

I had heard this from someone . Actually that person used this sentence when she was going to eat a dish . It is related to food . What does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

It means to begin eating something with pleasure or enjoyment. In American English the imperative verb phrase *Dig in!* is a rough idiomatic equivalent to the French *Bon Appetit!* It means to begin eating and enjoy. So, the given phrase *I am so digging into it* means that she is really looking forward to enjoying that food.